# How to combine two columns mysql

Tags: mysql

How would one combine the columns below into one column. I need them combined along with other information which I have excluded from this call ..

```
SELECT  n.news_id, e.event_id   
FROM events AS e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN news n 
 ON n.dealer_id = e.dealer_id
WHERE e.dealer_id = '99' 
ORDER BY n.news_id DESC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

what these combined opposed to this :

```
  news_id |  event_id
 --------- ----------
 |20083  | 1186     |
 |20083  | 1187     |
 |20083  | 1188     |
 |20083  | 1189     |
```

to something like this :

```
  id 
 --------- 
 |  1186 |
 |  1187 |
 |  1188 |
 |  1189 |
 |20083  | 
 |20083  | 
 |20083  | 
 |20083  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the SQL UNION-operator.

```
SELECT news_id FROM events
UNION
SELECT event_id FROM events
```

Though keep in mind that UNION operator removes duplicates. If you want to preserve duplicates, try with UNION ALL.

Comment: hmm it was having some issues with that but I could try that one, thanks for the tip... I was thinking of a GROUP BY instead ..